# mouseover toggleClass not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a Web Portfolio, but am trying to make it so that when I hover over the images of the websites I have created a border goes around it using js, css, and html 5. For some reason it still is not functioning though.

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.link_border').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("img_wrap");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("img_wrap");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.img_wrap {
    border: thick solid #FFFF00;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 210px;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    padding: 8px auto 3px auto;
    float: left;
    border: thin groove rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    clear: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="link_border" href="http://www.aolstudentsonline.com/jasoncameron//wd1/beatrice/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/beatriceimg_small.png" width="200" height="200"   alt="Beatrice Salon and Spa"></a> 
        <div class="text">
            <h2>Project: Beatrice Spa and Salon</h2>
            <h3>Type: School Project</h3>
            <h4>Skills Used: HTML, CSS, Javascript/Jquery,                Adobe Photoshop CS6/Illustrator CS6</h4> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `mouseover` only accepts one callback, not two !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to use JavaScript to do it, just use CSS Pseudo Selector [:HOVER]

//CHANGE CSS TO THIS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 210px;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    padding: 8px auto 3px auto;
    float: left;
    border: thin groove rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    clear: right;
}
.wrapper:hover {
    border: thick solid #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did work, need to figure out how to make it when I hover that it doesn't move things below it to make room for hte border, but it works.

Comment: Edit your HTML & CSS above and let me see whats going on now.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done in **pure CSS** using the `:hover` pseudo

```
.wrapper:hover a.link_border{
    border: thick solid #FFFF00;
}
```

---

*If for some reason you need jQuery to do more crazy stuff I'm not aware of...*

- your selector `a .link_border` **should be:** `a.link_border`
- the `.mouseover()` method, **it does not accepts** 2 callback functions.

***use this instead:***

```
<script>

$(function(){ // DOM is now ready (shorthand)

    $('a.link_border').hover(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("img_wrap");
    });

});

</script>
```

If you really want to **control both events** `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` trough the `.hover()` Method:

```
    $('a.link_border').hover(function() {
       $(this).addClass("img_wrap");
       // other stuff for mouseenter....
    }, function(){
       $(this).removeClass("img_wrap");
       // other stuff for mouseleave....
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between your link and your class:

```
$('a .link_border')
```

It should read:

```
$('a.link_border')
```

Also, change `mouseover` to `hover`.

Comment: sadly removing the space did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: removed the space changed to .hover method, but it is still not showing hte yellow border around the image.